# video tag not showing the video url

Tags: java, android, html, facebook, http

I am performing an https request to using android to facebook video url 
I am getting in response a video tag not containing the src of the video 
but when the tag on the web browser contains the src 
what I am getting :

```
<video height="720" width="720" preload="auto" class="_ox1" data-video-width="720" data-video-height="720" id="u_0_1"><div class="_ox1" data-flash="1" id="id_563318ccbadc99b34985536" data-fallback-markup="1" data-video-width="720" data-video-height="720" style="width:720px;height:720px"></div></video>
```

the tag in the browser :

```
<video height="720" width="720" preload="auto" class="_ox1" data-video-width="720" data-video-height="720" id="u_0_5" src="https://video-fra3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hvideo-xaf1/v/t42.1790-2/11828108_966111320095232_778529263_n.mp4?efg=eyJybHIiOjMwMCwicmxhIjo1MTIsInZlbmNvZGVfdGFnIjoicWZfNDI2d19jcmZfMjNfbWFpbl8zLjBfcDFoY19zZCJ9&amp;rl=300&amp;vabr=80&amp;oh=b7fe85321c8b179be254a93690b1e15a&amp;oe=56333D2B" aria-owns="js_1" aria-haspopup="true" tabindex="0"><noscript data-reactid=".10"></noscript></video>
```

My http request code :

```
URL obj = new URL("https://www.facebook.com/3a2ilati/videos/1003710002994516/");
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
            int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { // success
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        con.getInputStream()));
                String inputLine;
                StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(inputLine);
                }
                in.close();
```

so what should I do to display the src ?

Comment: or why is this thing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solve  it , it seems that facebook does not gives the link directly until the user press the play button so I got the html to a web view the executing javascript code via javascript interface which is video.pause() to get the src of the video

Comment: You should be able to get the video file's URI from the Graph API (look for the `source` field in the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video))